How to connect .env file for API
I've been trying to add .env file for my API project (API in Flask; python with mongoDB database) and I'm not really sure how to do it - CI/CD keeps failing because of this file being missing.
Currently I was trying to add it as an repository secrets, I'm just not really sure if I should add entire .env file as a single secret, or each variable included in .env as a different secret in repository - I tried both and both failed, does naming of secrets have any influence on how they are being found by API on GitHub during the CI/CD??
Here is the .yml code that I have to run the API on each Pull request (it is some basic file based on tutorials):
name: ci-cd
 on:
  pull_request:
  branches: [ "main" ]

 # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
 workflow_dispatch:

 jobs: 
  ci:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps: 
  - name: Set up Python 3.9
    uses: actions/setup-python@v2
    with:
      python-version: 3.9

  - name: Check-out repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  # Creating and activating a virtual environment
  - name: Set up virtual environment
    run: python3 -m venv venv
  - name: Activate virtual environment
    run: source venv/bin/activate

  - name: Setup .env file
    run: |
      echo "${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT_FILE }}" > key.env.asc
      gpg -d --passphrase "${{ secrets.ENV_PASSWORD }}" --batch key.env.asc > key.env

  # Install dependencies from requirements.txt
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install -r requirements.txt
      pip install pytest pytest-cov
      pip install coverage

    #Builds project before testing
 # - name: Build project
  #  run: python3 main.py

  # Run unittest tests
  - name: Run unittest tests
    run: python -m unittest discover -s tests -p 'test*.py'

  # Generate coverage report
  - name: Generate coverage report
    run: coverage xml -i

  #installs poetry for dependency management
  #- name: Install poetry
  #  uses: snok/install-poetry@v1
  #- name: Install package
  #  run: poetry install

  #- name: Test with pytest
  #  run: pytest tests/ --cov=controllers/UsersController.py --cov-report=xml

  - name: Use Codecov to track coverage
    uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
    with:
      files: ./coverage.xml   # report of test code coverage

Here is the error code returned by github actions - it failed at the "Setup .env file" step:
 0s
 Run echo "" > key.env.asc
 gpg: directory '/home/runner/.gnupg' created
 gpg: keybox '/home/runner/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
 gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=0a)
 Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

How exactly should I be providing the .env file through repository variables?

Can you edit your questions to include how you are planning to deploy. You keep talking about CI/CD but I unable to expand your questions to give you meaningful answer.

@RajaSimon thanks - I've edited the code by adding the .yml file used in github actions, it just should be some simple code that runs my API on each pull_request - but it fails on the .env stage thats why I'm asking on how to add those secrets to github repository propperly (I think I'm missing something there and that causes the failed runs)
